# Make: variable requirements that depend on the target

Tags: makefile

## Make: variable requirements that depend on the target

I have a `Makefile` that looks roughly like this:

```
default: en

.PHONY: default en es

en: NUMBER=number
es: NUMBER=numero

TARGET=$(NUMBER)-word
INTERMEDIATE=$(NUMBER)-tmp

en: number
es: number

number: $(INTERMEDIATE)
  touch $(TARGET)

$(INTERMEDIATE):
  @echo Please provide file $(INTERMEDIATE)
  @exit 1

clean:
  rm *-word *-tmp
```

To use it, you'd call `make en` (also a default) or `make es`. As I see it, this Makefile has two main features:

- An intermediate requirement (`$(INTERMEDIATE)`) has to be provided ahead of time by the user.
- This requirement is a variable whose value depends on the target.

When I run this, I get the following:

```
$ make
Please provide file number-tmp
make: *** [-tmp] Error 1
```

This error suggests to me that variables are resolved one stage too late for what I intend. The failing rule is `-tmp`, implying it can't tell the value of `$(NUMBER)` when deciding what rules to run. However it's resolved by the time it's running the rule.

So how could I make this work?

Comment: Your question is unclear. How do you want the user to choose between `en` and `es`? If `en` is the default, should the user who wants `es` run "make es"?

Comment: Apologies, you are correct. I have added usage instructions to the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Target_002dspecific.html) is clear that you cannot use target-specific variable values inside targets or prerequisites:

> The other exception is target-specific variable values. This feature allows you to define different values for the same variable, based on the target that make is currently building. **As with automatic variables, these values are only available within the context of a target’s recipe (and in other target-specific assignments).**

There are multiple ways you could handle this.  The simplest would be to change the selection to using a variable instead of a target, and use [constructed macro names](http://make.mad-scientist.net/constructed-macro-names/).  Suppose you stored the value in the `LV` variable (you should not use `LANG` etc. because this is special to the shell), like this:

```
# Must be set on the command line
LV =

en_NUMBER := number
es_NUMBER := numero

TARGET := $($(LV)_NUMBER)-word
INTERMEDIATE := $($(LV)_NUMBER)-tmp

ifeq ($(TARGET),-word)
  $(error Missing/invalid LV value: '$(LV)')
endif

number: $(INTERMEDIATE)
        touch $(TARGET)

clean:
        rm *-word *-tmp
```

If you run `make LV=en` you'll get `number-word`.  If you run `make LV=es` you'll get `numero-word`.  If you run `make` (no setting) or `make LV=foo` (invalid setting) you'll get an error.

There are other ways to do this but without a complete understanding of what you want we can't say for sure.

Comment: Thank you, your answer covers my case. I'm realising that my use of a language as a variable can confuse things: it may look like I want to do something locale-dependent (not the case, it was just an example).