# My linux c++ gnu makefile variable expansion does not behave as I expected it to

Tags: c++, linux, makefile

I have created the following little makefile snippet. **Note:** I have made this a minimal example of my problem so it is a pointless makefile.

```
TARGET = none
OBJ_BASE_DIR = obj

# Linux x86 c++ compiler
.PHONY: build_cpp_x86Linux
build_cpp_x86Linux: TARGET = x86Linux
build_cpp_x86Linux: build

OBJ_DIR = $(addsuffix /$(TARGET),$(OBJ_BASE_DIR))

$(info TARGET IS: $(TARGET))
$(info OBJ_DIR IS: $(OBJ_DIR))

build: $(OBJ_DIR)/test.o
    @echo building, OBJ_DIR: $(OBJ_DIR)

# pattern rule
$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o:
    @echo "compiling $@"
```

Here is the output of calling `make`:

> ```
> TARGET IS: none
> OBJ_DIR IS: obj/none
> compiling obj/none/test.o
> building, OBJ_DIR: obj/x86Linux
> ```

From the output you can see that it is trying to compile `obj/none/test.o`, but what I want it to do is try to compile `obj/x86Linux/test.o`. I am not quite sure what is going on here. I think I understand that the makefile expands the variables on the first pass (which would result in TARGET=none), but I thought that it would re-expand the variables again once I have called the target `build_cpp_x86Linux` which sets the value of TARGET to x86Linux...

What I am doing wrong here and how should this be done?

Comment: Note: `.PHONEY` --> `.PHONY`.

Comment: @G.M. good spot.. fixed

Comment: It's possible to fix this with second-expansion, but you *really* shouldn't use targets for the job of a makefile. And if you *do* want to use targets, call another makefile recursively.

Comment: @o11c hmm.... how can this be solved with second-expansion?, I took a look at this but could not quite figure out how to use it for this purpose.  Also re: calling makefile I don't get if you mean call the "makefile recursively" or "call another makefile".... I think I get how each of those could work (by passing variables into the second makefile call... : )

Comment: Is "none" even a real value, or is it just a dummy?

Comment: See my answer from an hour or so ago to understand why you are getting the results you get: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53364648/939557  Note I'm not suggesting the same solution just explaining why you get the `none` value in the compile rule.

Comment: @amn well... its a dummy value, but in reality it would be the default value.

Comment: @MadScientist I do get your explanation thanks  (and upvoted). But I think its messy the user having to specify a variable to pass in because there is no auto complete. But I guess a way to get around that is to have a makefile with targets that call another makefile and pass in the variables (bit like what o11c is mentioning), just so that the user can use auto complete etc...

Comment: Well, as I said in that comment there are multiple ways to do it.  The secondary expansion suggestion made by o11c will work as well.

Comment: @MadScientist I don't suppose you could elaborate on how the secondary expansion would work for this case? .. I mean I have read roughly how it works, but I can't see how to apply it.. You can define an expansion like: OBJ_DIR=$$(TARGET) or some such, but I always seem to end up with OBJ_DIR being just $(TARGET) (i.e. one of the dollars is consumed...

Comment: Your question is vague because you are asking X while your problem is Y. We don't understand what Y is, because you only have tried to explain (rather vaguely) X. What is it that you're building? How many targets do you have? What are the process variables (those that should actually affect building as opposed to affecting make)? Make has implicit rules and is able to compile, build and link without you having to describe actual building steps. You only need to specify dependencies and variables like CFLAGS, LDFLAGS etc.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use:

```
TARGET?=none
```

And then override on the command line TARGET=x86Linux

You can also use `ifdef` or other scanning `if` operations to set different variables based on these arguments or environment variables.

Comment: Similar comment to MadScientists comment. Upvoted since it does work, but not quite right yet for me. But I think from what I have read so far a good approach for me is to have another layer of makefile to set these target variables and then call make again on another makefile or some such....